# How do I print two strings vertically side by side

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code where I want print two string vertically side by side like

```
hp
ea
lu
ll
o
```

but I am unable to print them
how do i modify my given code
my code is

```
s1='hello'
s2='paul'
i=0
while i<len(s1) and i<len(s2):
   print(s1[i],s2[i])
   i+=1
```

Comment: What's the problem with this…?

Comment: Use `zip_longest()`?

Answer (score 6):

this is a variant using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s1='hello'
s2='paul'

for a, b in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=' '):
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

To get your current code to work, you should use the `or` operator in your condition instead of `and`, and use a conditional operator to default your list values to a space if the index is not less than the length of the list:

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = 'paul'
i = 0
while i < len(s1) or i < len(s2):
    print(s1[i] if i < len(s1) else ' ', s2[i] if i < len(s2) else ' ')
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `zip_longest` here:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
s1 = 'hello'
    s2 = 'paul'
    for c1, c2 in zip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue=' '):
        print(c1, c2)
```

---

if you are not familiar with that, don't worry, you can use your version, I have fixed it, just **continue the while loop separately**:

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = 'paul'
i = 0
while i < len(s1) and i < len(s2):
    print(s1[i], s2[i])
    i += 1

while i < len(s1):
    print(s1[i], ' ')
    i += 1

while i < len(s2):
    print(' ', s2[i])
    i += 1
```

output:

```
h p
e a
l u
l l
o
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 1):

I like the zip method suggested by @Netwave but you must have strings of the same size for it to work.

Here a patched version:

```
s1 = 'Hello'
s2 = 'Paul'
#make strings equal in length
if len(s1) != len(s2):
    while len(s1) < len(s2):
        s1 += ' '
    while len(s2) < len(s1):
        s2 += ' '

txt = "\n".join(f"{x}{y}" for x, y in zip(s1, s2))
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
HP
ea
lu
ll
o
```